# Laravel Homestead SSH

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I've having some odd trouble trying to access Laravel Homestead on my local machine through SSH. I can run:

```
homestead up
```

with no problems and access my "website.local" through the browser. However when I run:

```
homestead ssh
```

OR

```
vagrant ssh
```

I receive the following information:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-30-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

System information as of Fri Jan  2 11:08:55 UTC 2015

System load:  0.0               Processes:           95
Usage of /:   5.1% of 39.34GB   Users logged in:     0
Memory usage: 35%               IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
Swap usage:   0%                IP address for eth1: 192.168.10.10

Graph this data and manage this system at:
https://landscape.canonical.com/

Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud


Last login: Fri Jan  2 11:08:55 2015 from 10.0.2.2
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

I must say this is absolutely baffling me as it was working fine as of last night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try the old-fashioned "off and on" again. Restart your machine and then try `homestead up` again.

The next step would be to destroy and rebuild your Homestead machine. Because all your configuration is in the `Homestead.yaml` file you won't lose anything (except the contents of any databases). Run `homestead destroy` and confirm, then `homestead up` again to rebuild it from scratch.

Alternatively, remove your Homestead configuration with `rm -rf ~/.homestead` (assuming you're on a Mac). Run `homestead init` and `homestead edit` to again configure your machine and finally `homestead up` to build it all again.

Finally, go and make sure you have installed the latest versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox, then update your Homestead installation with `composer global update`. Also run `homestead update` to make sure you've got the latest Homestead image. Then `homestead init` again to start from scratch running up to date.